# Gmail shows an email (categorized as inbox), in "all mail" but not in inbox

Tags: gmail

This is when I click on "All Mail"

[image: screen shot "All Mail"]

And this is when I click on Inbox

[image: screen shot "Inbox"]

Notice that in the "All Mail" pic, the category is "Inbox" for the bunch of recent emails. Whereas in the "Inbox" pic, the last email showing is from Apr 24, and the ones today april 25th (3:52am, 6:55am,....) aren't showing.

Comment: Check your filters and make sure you don't have a filter affecting the missing email.  It is common to set a filter that causes a message to bypass the inbox and go directly to archive (or to a label.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your screen shot shows you're looking at the *Primary* tab. Conversations categorized as *Social* or *Promotions* are also in the Inbox, but are displayed on the matching tab.

Comment: I have some emails that are in all mail, but are not showing up in any tab. From a new website too.. not sure what's going on.. might have something to do with using Inbox

Comment: @DevinGRhode: If it's not showing up in any tab, then it has been archived (aka the Inbox tag has been removed).

Comment: I'm really not sure what's going on, I have lots of mail not showing up in any tab but is present in All Mail. That's actually all I've been using because reliability comes first. I've unsubscribed from a lot of stuff, but ready to use gmail tabs again... I might go through and do some massive cleanup of my filters, and then hopefully I'll figure out what the issue is. I'm guessing it has something to do with me using inbox.google.com... but not sure

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to Settings -> Filters and Blocked Addresses and check if you have a filter in place that would apply to the missing emails.  It is possible that you have a filter with "Skip the Inbox" checked, which would archive the email in the "All Mail" area.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This "All Mail" but not arriving in the In-box has been a problem with Gmail for many years. Unfortunately, the "simple" explanations posted above does NOT explain this phenomenon.  I've been fighting it for years and finally decided that it was a major bug in GMail.

I finally implemented the work-around of adding filters which applied to particular "TO addresses" and did a "Never send it to Spam" on the "missing" email.   (I had found that similar experiments with a filter for "Mark it as important" or "Categorize as Personal"  did NOT help the situation.)

I do wish Google would fix this problem. It began to appear around 2010, if I recall.

Comment: The problem I describe seems to be from a somewhat understandable feature, one of the other categories like promotional, didn't count as inbox mail(see the answer I accepted a day after I asked the question).  If you have run into a different problem then you should make a question and show screenshots proving it.

Comment: I have this issue, consider upvoting for visibility..

Comment: I have some emails that don't show up in any tab.. only in all mail

Comment: I still have the same problem, a letter shows up only in 'all mail' but not in any category and not in the inbox either. Wish anyone cared enough to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I thought at first that my emails don't show in the inbox, but they do appeared in All Mail or when I searched them exclusivly. 
As in your case, the emails were labeled as "inbox"

In my case, I needed to cancel the new inbox type tabs (Promotion tab, social tab, etc'... )

to do that:
[image]

then in the pop-up window
[image]